# Mapping UI elements in a Logical Data Model

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I'm currently in a project where I have been asked to create a logical data model in UML. Now i've defined all my logical data entities and know all my attributes i'm just a little lost on how I can map these attributes to the UI.

The point of the exercise is to prove all the attributes in the requirements have been met in the system we have chosen to deploy. Happy to supply more information.

The application I am using is Enterprise Architect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was solved the Enterprise Architect Support Forums.

```
Connect both classes with an association
Right click the assoc. near the class with attributes
Context menu/Link to Element Feature
Attributes
-> select the one and the assoc. is attached to it
```

Comment: Are you able to supply the forum link so others can lookup the original context?

Comment: To go a bit farther ... you can right-click near both ends of the association and link the two attributes directly together.  This is exactly what I was looking for an it worked brilliantly.  Thanks for not keeping the answer to yourself, AshHimself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant approach which is to use Database stereotypes in your class diagram on attributes and then map it to java ORM annotation in the code.
I don't think EA can do this ORM mapping but other tools can.

Comment: I don't have access to any code nor should we be using the database data either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have artifacts in your model for the UI, too? That is, as a screen mock up or as a class model of the underlying UI classes? If yes, then you may find it very helpful to establish a traceability for your artifacts using a realization or dependency relationship.

You can further support that by creating requirement entities (in a SysML requirements diagram) and drag'n'drop the respective requirement onto the entity which provides a solution to it. This is described on page 31 in the following EA whitepaper: http://community.sparxsystems.com/whitepapers/Requirements%20Management%20with%20Enterprise%20Architect/Requirements_Management_in_Enterprise_Architect.pdf

I made a screenshot for you of how this looks, but unfortunately I am not yet allowed to post it here since I am a new member. Maybe you can get a rough idea from this screenshot I found on the web: http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise-architect/images/traceability_lg.png

That mechanism works on class level. On the attribute level you may want to add a link to specific related (requirements) elements in the notes field, if necessary.

Comment: Hi observer, thanks for the detailed reply. I don't have any requirements in EA. In simpler terms. I need to link my attributes to UI elements. I see you have attributes in your diagram and I need to link those attributes some how. I don't think its possible.